# How to read the Mobilenet pretrained model names?

Tags: tensorflow

The pretrained Mobilenet models download page consists of many models named like these,

MobileNet_v1_**1.0**_**160**

What does the 1.0 and 160 refers to in these cases ?

link to the downloads site - [mobilenet link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.md)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.0 refers to a model hyperparameter alpha, the 160 to the input image size. See https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/blob/master/mobilenet.py